# Jquery add and remove attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want my listed items to add a ID on click, how can i do that? Or what am i doing wrong?

```
$('.ex-menuLi #tt').attr('id', 'test');
$('.ex-menuLi').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('id', 'test').siblings().removeAttr('id', 'test');
});
```

```html
<nav id="extraMenu">
    <!--<ul id="ex-menuUl"> -->
    <li class="ex-menuLi" id="ex-menuLiId"><a href="#" class="test1" id="tt">Test</a></li>
    <li class="ex-menuLi" id="ex-menuLiId"><a href="#" class="test1">Test2</a></li>
    <li class="ex-menuLi" id="ex-menuLiId"><a href="#" class="test1">Test3</a></li>
<!--</ul>-->
</nav>
```

```css
#test{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: and do the same thing with class and you get your work done

Comment: Why have you commented out the opening, and closing, tag of your list? Without those tags your HTML is invalid. Also "*…else it will not work with the rest of my code*" – then the rest of your code needs fixing, don't break one thing to account for errors elsewhere, do it properly/safely and with validity.

Answer (score 0):

//You can do something like this to set the uniqueid

```
$('.ex-menuLi').each(function(index){
   $(this).attr('id', index)
 });
```